# Retrive value of a column in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have made a table in **Parse.com** using **Dashboard** name **Blogs**. I have made a column **url** type **String** using **Dashboard** inside it where I have to post blogs url and I have posted some url inside this column by adding rows. Now I am trying to get these values inside my application by using this code in onCreate() method.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Blogs");
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("url", true);
List<ParseObject> objects = null;
try {
    objects = parseQuery.find();
    }
catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting **objects** of size 0. I am unable to understand how to get my **url** column  all values.

Comment: Did you get any Exceptions?

Comment: No . I used debugger and it didn't go to catch part.@ching . if there is any other way to get all column value then tell me.

Comment: actually I did not created the table by application. I created it by dashboard and I am using values in from it in applications @ching

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Blogs");
```

**parseQuery.whereEqualTo("url","true");**

```
List<ParseObject> objects = null;
try 
{
   objects = parseQuery.find();
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{
   Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is your Column type as Boolean ? Try like this ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = new ParseQuery("Blogs");

Comment: No it is String type.

Comment: does ur column contains value ?need more information.. I mean did u set ACL for this ?

Comment: ya I have put urls like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186388/retrive-value-of-a-column-in-parse-com

Comment: I did not make it by code. I made it in dashboard and then trying to retrieve values in application

Answer (score 0):

Read the [api docs](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html) carefully.
I believe you want to query if the urls exists in the column. (since you have used `parseQuery.whereEqualTo("url", true);`)

From the docs,

```
public ParseQuery<T> whereEqualTo(String key,
                                  Object value)
```

What it does : Add a constraint to the query that requires a particular key's value to be equal to the provided value.

So in this case for url, the value should be a String (which you want to match to) if you have defined the column as String. Putting value as boolean will give you undesired result.

If you want to check if the column url exists for the object,
then use `whereExists(String key)`.